# UIScrollView height to adjust when width is adjusted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView and I wanted the frame height to adjust proportionally when I adjust the width, is this possible? Basically I am talking about auto adjusting the frame height of the UIScrollView when I adjust the width of the UIScrollView? I have tried setting the autoResizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and height, but this doesn't work

Comment: How are you "adjusting the width" of the scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an automatic way to do it.  but you can added a UIView+SCaleAddition to do this:

```
@interface UIView(RespectScale)
- (void)setWidthRespect:(float)w;
- (void)setHeightRespect:(float)h;
@end

@implement UIView(RespectScale)
- (void)setWidthRespect:(float)w
{
   float scale = self.bounds.size.width / self.bounds.size.height;
   float h = w/scale;
   CGRect bounds = self.bounds
   bounds.size.width = w;
   bounds.size.height = h;
   self.bounds = bounds;
}

- (void)setHeightRespect:(float)h
{
  //  write it your own
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
//get old proportions
CGFloat proportion = scrollView.frame.size.width / scrollView.frame.size.height;

CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;

frame.size.width = new_width;
frame.size.height = new_width * proportion;

scrollView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: that's what I did, but was wondering if there's an automatic way without having to do this

Comment: well you can apply a CGAffineTransformScale, but other than that, I don't think so.